# How to write-access a string variable from a TParallel.For loop thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

In a `System.Threading.TParallel.For` loop, I need to write-access a string variable which is declared outside of the `TParallel.For` loop threads:

```
// Main thread:
procedure TForm2.GetWeather;
var
  CurrentWeather: string;
begin
  CurrentWeather := 'Current weather: ';

  System.Threading.TParallel.For(1, 10,
    procedure(idx: Integer)
    begin
      if IsRainy(idx) then
      begin
        // loop thread needs to write-access a mainthread-string-variable:
        CurrentWeather := CurrentWeather + 'bad weather, ';
      end;
    end);

  Self.Caption := CurrentWeather;
end;
```

But according to the documentation, this should not be done. And `System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked` doesn't seem to have a method to write to a string variable.

So how can I write to the *CurrentWeather* variable in this case?

Delphi 10.1.2 Berlin

EDIT:

Following the advice of David Heffernan I rewrote the code - is this correct?:

```
// Main thread:
procedure TForm2.GetWeather;
var
  CurrentWeather: string;
  ALock: TCriticalSection;
begin
  CurrentWeather := 'Current weather: ';

  ALock := TCriticalSection.Create;
  try
    System.Threading.TParallel.For(1, 10,
      procedure(idx: Integer)
      begin
        if IsRainy(idx) then
        begin
          ALock.Enter;
          try
            CurrentWeather := CurrentWeather + 'bad weather, ';
          finally
            ALock.Leave;
          end;
        end;
      end);
  finally
    ALock.Free;
  end;

  Self.Caption := CurrentWeather;
end;
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that, in a situation like this, the overhead of the critical section might remove any benefits coming from multithreading.

Comment: That depends on how many times the condition is met. If you live in the Sahara for example, the above loop would be rather fast... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a lock to modify complex data types like `string`. This cannot be done atomically.

Use `TCriticalSection` if you target just Windows. For code that targets other platforms then you should use `TMonitor`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `TThread.Queue`, for example like this (this assumes that you want to update caption dynamically, rather than accumulate result and show it after all threads are finished)

```
procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := 'Current weather: ';
  TParallel.For(1, 10,
    procedure(idx: Integer)
    begin
      if IsRainy(idx) then
      begin
        // loop thread needs to write-access a mainthread-string-variable:
        TThread.Queue(TThread.Current,
        procedure
        begin
          Caption := Caption + 'bad weather, ';
        end)
      end;
    end);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a little bit different from my original code which is a simplification of a more complex scenario: Repeatedly modifying a local string variable in a `TParallel.For` loop and then USING the string variable right after the loop. I wonder whether `TThread.Queue` would not possibly act too late sometimes if I use the variable right after the loop?

Comment: Correct. You'd need to `Queue` any post loop action also. Probably not what you are looking for, and perhaps heavy weight too.

Comment: Yes it will be late, in this case you need different solution